# NSURL is returning nil for a valid URL

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I have a valid URL for google maps , which if you run in your browser would show an image of a map. However, when I put it inside my Swift code and try to create an NSURL from String it returns nil

```
let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=hybrid&center=37.33233141,-122.0312186&path=color:0xff0000|weight:10|37.33233141,-122.0312186|21.422570,%2039.826190&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C37.33233141,-122.0312186&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C21.422570,39.826190&zoom=1&size=1080x1920"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
```

Currently , this returns nil, I don't know why. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I suggest that you open up a playground and try to remove strange characters (:, |) until it works.

Comment: The given string is definitely not a valid url string. The culprit is the character "|" which is not allowed in the query component. Since the query component seems to be encoded already, this also indicates a bug in the browser: if the browser had done it right it had _percent escaped_ the `|` character to `%7C`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work: Here is why http://www.url-encode-decode.com

```
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

Since above API is deprecated alternative approach is

```
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations of why should your code works? Code-only answers are  not very useful for other readers that stumble upon this question.

Comment: @Cristik. Please check answer now.

Comment: @real19 Applying this function only happens to work. Given that the provided string is a malformed url, and the docs explicitly state that this function is problematic to "cure" partly escaped url strings, and the fact that this function is also _deprecated_ -- I would strongly suggest not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString:):

> This method expects URLString to contain only characters that are allowed in a properly formed URL. All other characters must be properly percent escaped. Any percent-escaped characters are interpreted using UTF-8 encoding.

Likely there's something incorrect in your string, and you need to encode it before passing it to `NSURL`, you can do this via `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`:

```
if let encodedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet() {
    url = NSURL(string: urlString)
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the OPs question, actually the given URL string is not a valid url string. It's already encoded. So, you actually double percent encode it.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper hmm... you have a valid point, for this particular question it works as the query is the invalid one `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()` doesn't affect the characters in the URL. So the function returns a valid url. Still, not the best solution to address all possible scenarios...

Comment: Since the given URL string is malformed, we should expect nothing from functions which take this as input. Instead, we should try to fix the thing where this malformed string comes from. The relevant RFCs have clearly defined how a valid URL string should look like. There's also a BNF given, which makes it easy to compose and parse strings. The web already exists for decades - and we should expect these things eventually working correct now. But, it's still funny to see, how these very basic and crucial things can go wrong  ;)