# Why won't NSURL accept a valid string that contains quotes or braces?

Tags: swift, nsurl

*EDIT*

```
https://www.someurl.com/search?&access_token=1,84,848473938;848483,83&_json={"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

When declaring a URL that has a JSON string, I obviously need to use braces `_json={ }` and qoutes `\"key1\":\"value1\"`

`NSURL(string: String)`, however, magically becomes `nil` if either of these characters are included in the string.

So as answered correctly here: [NSURL is returning nil for a valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805082/nsurl-is-returning-nil-for-a-valid-url), I tried using:

```
let url = NSURL(string: url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)
```

But I believe that's deprecated since it was before Swift 2 was released and I am getting the error:  `cannot convert value of Type NSCharacterSet to expected argument type NSStringEncoding (aka UInt)`

So I tried using

```
let url = NSURL(string: url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!
```

and while that did allow NSURL to have a value instead of nil, it did not return the expected results, so something is still wrong.

I know that the format is correct, because if I type the URL string manually in a browser, I get the expected result.  If i copy/paste the encoded version from Xcode, it gives me the wrong result as did Swift when encoding as shown above.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the specific string you're trying to use?

Comment: Am I understanding it right that you're trying to put a JSON object in an URL?

Comment: Yes I'm putting a JSON object in my string. I've used the 'stringByAddingPerecent...' (I forget the exact call name offhand), but that doesn't change all the objects. It changes the braces and quotes, but not the commas. I included a function to manually change the characters and have successfully received the response new I want. I've edited my OP to include the strong in question.

Comment: What's the advantage of `&_json={"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}` over `?key1=value1&key2=value2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify a mutable character set to remove an allowed character: since you want the commas to be encoded, remove the comma from the `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` before using it.

In **Swift 2**, we need to dance with `NSMutableCharacterSet` like this:

```
let sourceURL = "https://www.someurl.com/search?&access_token=1,84,848473938;848483,83&_json={\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"

let charSet = NSMutableCharacterSet()
charSet.formUnionWithCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
charSet.removeCharactersInString(",")

let url = NSURL(string: sourceURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(charSet)!)

print(url!)
```

Prints:

> https://www.someurl.com/search?&access_token=1%2C84%2C848473938;848483%2C83&_json=%7B%22key1%22:%22value1%22%2C%22key2%22:%22value2%22%7D

To do the same thing with **Swift 3** we're using the `CharacterSet` struct instead of `NSMutableCharacterSet` but it's the same idea:

```
var charSet = CharacterSet()
charSet.formUnion(.urlQueryAllowed)
charSet.remove(",")
if let encoded = sourceURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: charSet) {
    if let url = URL(string: encoded) {
        print(url)
    }
}
```