# Google Maps API: String URL Enconding

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, url, swift3

I'm using the following code to search for a place:

```
let correctedAddress:String! = self.searchResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.symbols)

let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)&sensor=false")
```

self.searchResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] returns a string like this: *"São Paulo - State of São Paulo, Brazil"*

The string that is the parameter of URL is like this (after the encoding):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Optional(\%22State%20of%20S%C3%A3o%20Paulo%2C%20Brazil\%22)&sensor=false
```

If I search for this URL in my web browser, the JSON is shown. So I assume it is a valid URL, but the URL(string: ..) method always returns *nil*

I probably need to change my encoding, I tried using CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed but always return nil.

What kind of encoding I should use? Or there is something else wrong?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?  I have the same issue.  I tried to see if the answer from the following helped, but I still couldn't get it to work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805082/nsurl-is-returning-nil-for-a-valid-url

Comment: @Ben No. Since I am already using the percent encoding and most of the answers were saying to add that, I couldn't get the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove the Optional(...) string in the url

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\%22State%20of%20S%C3%A3o%20Paulo%2C%20Brazil\%22&sensor=false

I believe that's the reason for the URL is returning `nil`.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how to do this?  I'm running into the same issue with the Swift 3.0 update.  I tried to force unwrap url variable, but that causes a crash also.

Comment: that worked. I changed to `let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + correctedAddress + "&sensor=false")` it worked

Answer (score 0):

***This worked for me :***

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + correctedAddress + "&sensor=false"